# Get the tools for XNA development

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, xna, xna-4.0

I've followed this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx) link  but there's no link there for Windows games. Only these two:

1. App Hub - Download free tools... to develop games and apps for **Xbox**
   LIVE Indie Games and Windows **Phone** 7.
2. Xbox 360 - Resources and programs ... development for the **Xbox 360**.

Where do I get the tools for developing for PC's? Or does that not even exist?

Also, is my understanding that a user will have to download some redistributable for using the game correct? And that though it seems MS will cease support ['soon'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) - it should still be available after that, like Winforms is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant you're looking for the link to download XNA 4.0, here it is:http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714. And I think that you can include the redistributable file with your game so the user doesn't have to download the file from the web, thought I'm not sure about this. Here's a link to the XNA 4.0 redistributable http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20914. Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Microsoft has dropped support for the XNA framework, but there is great work being done to keep it alive, and improve upon it with MonoGame.

http://monogame.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks. But what about my main question?

Comment: At the moment, it seems like XNA support is being dropped by Microsoft next year. I believe this does mean that it is still available but there will be no further development.
As far as the tools needed: I'm able to use VS2012 Express and the download of MonoGame from the above link to develop games for the PC (and can be converted to other platforms as well).